# Automatic layout tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, browser, jenkins

Is there any tool for testing that layout for a website dont generate visual bugs?
Im working on a site where sometimes we can see visual bugs. Example:

There is a page where objects are listed. The listing is divided in pages.
Last time, after browsing a few page, I saw that a particular page showed a visual bug, in this case the table became wider than normally.
In this case the problem was that one of the td-tags contained too much text which made all the table become wider.

Maybe this can sound like a crazy thing? But my client thinks there is a way to set up this kind of tests and acording to him Jenkins can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to automate layout testing of a web application using Galen Framework. This tool has its own language and is very easy to learn and understand. It is a Selenium based and you can run test in Selenium Grid, [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/) if you want to test your application in different browsers.

This tool gets the location of specified element on page and check them relatively to each other.

Example: if you want to check that menu pane is below header and stretches to the width of a browser and has 50 pixel height, you can do it like this:

```
menu
    below: header 5px
    width: 100% of screen/width
    height: 50px
```

This tool can also be used to test responsive designs.

You can find complete documentation on official website http://galenframework.com

The best part is you can even create JAVA Tests. Galen JavaScript API is also available along with the sample projects in github.

Again, test(s) written once can be used at multiple phases of application lifecycle.